# How to to make that my button change text to random text I want? (ADT)

Tags: android, button, adt

I had some issue when I tryed to change my text to some other text I wanted but tt didnt work. But that doesnt matter now. I just started my Project and here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.what.ever;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Can you guys give me a code that change my text (spring/text1) with button (string/button1) to random text I write? Some thing like :

```
textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textik);
                pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);}

                final String[] myNicknames = {"Tom", "John", "Nikolaj", "Gabriel"};

            pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int rando = (int) (Math.random() *4);
                textOne.setText(myNicknames[rando]);

            }
        });
        }
```

I will be very thankful if it work! :3

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: With that second code yes, app doesnt start at all, but the issue is this line I thing -> 
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
Couse Im doing it by one tutorial but he doesnt have it in there (that line IF....) And when I cut it out it doesnt work too...So I thing the code I use is outdated or something... Do you know what I have to change so it works how I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You have to find your button and Textview in onCreateView() of the Fragment. this will work.

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                        textOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textik);
                        pushMe = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                        final String[] myNicknames = {"Tom", "John", "Nikolaj", "Gabriel"};

                    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        int rando = (int) (Math.random() % 4);
                        textOne.setText(myNicknames[rando]);
                       }
                });

                    return rootView;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it now, then I info does it work or no

Comment: Ok. let me know that.

Comment: Finnaly I tried it now and it helped a little, like now my app does not crash when I open it but its blank (whole screen is white I can see only app name and thats all. Here is my code now, so can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: private String[] myNicknames;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                     final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                         final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                         Button pushMe = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                         myNicknames = new String[] {"Tom", "John", "Nikolaj", "Gabriel"};

Comment: ushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         int rando = (int) (Math.random() % 4);
                         text2.setText(myNicknames[rando]);
                        }
                 });

                     return rootView;
                 }

Comment: What about your xml? Is it contains a FrameLayout with id container? Read this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419924/android-adding-a-fragment-to-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

```
final  String[] Textlist = { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3"};

TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

Random random = new Random();

String randomText = TextList[random.nextInt(TextList.length)];

yourTextView.setText(randomText);
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer